# Tool Navigation Drawer - Switch Case

Tags: android, android-fragments, switch-statement, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

Hi I am trying to get a switch case statement to work for the navigation drawer for an android app. I have done to an onclick event to open the one activity, no matter what fragment you want to open. I know the structure of what I have to do (get the id of the selected item and open that fragment). Could someone just tell me where be best to input the piece of could and how to start if of.

Navigation Drawer Activity:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements BCRfmAdapter.ClickListener{


private RecyclerView recyclerView;
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToogle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

private BCRfmAdapter adapter;

private View containerView;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    adapter = new BCRfmAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position)
        {

        }
    }));

    return layout;
}

public static List<Information> getData() {
    //load only static data inside a drawer
    List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_facebook, R.drawable.ic_facebook, R.drawable.ic_twitter, R.drawable.ic_action_about, R.drawable.ic_contact, R.drawable.ic_action_about};
    String[] titles = {"Listen Live", "Facebook", "Twitter", "Google+", "About BCR FM", "Contact Us"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Information current = new Information();
        current.iconId = icons[i % icons.length];
        current.title = titles[i % titles.length];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;

    //twitter://user?user_id=1721642934
    //Started to add each item to the list rather than using an array..
    // Add Drawer Item to dataList
    /*data.add(new Information("Listen LIve", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    data.add(new Information("Facebook", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    data.add(new Information("Twitter", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    data.add(new Information("About BCRFm", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
    data.add(new Information("Contact Us", R.drawable.ic_action_email));*/
}

//TODO switch case
@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), devActivity.class));
}

public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
}

public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
    containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    mDrawerToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
        }
    };
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);
    }
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToogle);
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToogle.syncState();
        }
    });

}

static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener){
        this.clickListener=clickListener;
        gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child=recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if(child!=null && clickListener!=null)
                {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child=rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(child!=null && clickListener!=null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e))
        {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) { }
}

public static interface ClickListener{
    public void onClick(View view, int position);
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}
}
```

And here is my DrawerAdapter code:

```
public class BCRfmAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BCRfmAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
private ClickListener clickListener;


public BCRfmAdapter(Context context, List<Information> data){
    this.context=context;
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Information current=data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.title);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {return data.size();}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView title;
    ImageView icon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
        icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, devActivity.class));

        if(clickListener != null)
        {
            clickListener.itemClicked(v, getPosition());
        }
    }
}

public interface ClickListener{
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position);
}

public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
    this.clickListener=clickListener;
}
}
```

Comment: I would recommend following this: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html